# Angular 6 - Route Guard based on firestore node values

Tags: angular, google-cloud-firestore, angular-route-guards

I'm currently building an Angular project with Firestore. I have a `users` collection which contains a users `uid` plus their name, email and company name. Upon logging in, I can successfully take the users uid, look up the document in firestore and then redirect them to `domain.com/theircompanyname` - `theircompanyname` is what's stored in firestore under the user collection > document.

However, this currently doesn't prevent anyone entering a company name to the url and successfully navigating there. How would I go about implementing a route guard that only grants access to users who have a matching company to that which is visible in the url?

**login.ts**

```
login(email: string, password:string) {
  this.afAuth.auth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password).then(value => {
      const user_id = value.user.uid;
      this.userService.checkUserForCorrectRedirect(user_id)
  });
}
```

**user.service.ts**
This will redirect the user to the appropriate URL based on their company name in firestore (which i check by passing the user_id from login to this function)

```
checkUserForCorrectRedirect(user_id: string) {
   var docRef = this.db.collection("users").doc(`${user_id}`);

   docRef.get().then((doc) => {
    if (doc.exists) {
        const data = doc.data();
        this.company = data.company;
        this.router.navigate(['e', data.company]);
    } else {
        // doc.data() will be undefined in this case
        console.log("No such document!");
    }
 }).catch((error) => {
    console.log("Error getting document:", error);
 });
}
```

All of the above works. The route guard is what I'd like assistance with if possible please.

**router.guard**
This doesn't work obviously, and I don't really know how to make this work.

```js
 import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { ActivatedRouteSnapshot, RouterStateSnapshot, CanActivate, Router } from '@angular/router';
import { UserService } from '../services/user.service';

@Injectable()

export class AuthGuardService implements CanActivate {

    authGuardStateURL: string;

    constructor(
        private router: Router,
        private userService: UserService,
    ) { }



    canActivate(route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot, state: RouterStateSnapshot){
        if (this.userService.company == "testcompany") {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }

    }
```

Comment: can you show your router guard code?

Comment: Added. However, it's pretty useless as it's so bad... :)

Comment: what is the return value of `this.userService.company`

Comment: Whatever their company name is. Upon logging in, I take the user id, look up their document in firestore an update a company variable in the user.service.ts - That's what I'm hoping to check against. Not sure if that's the right approach.

Comment: Can you post the code of your method `this.userService.company`.

Comment: ` if (this.userService.company == "testcompany")` does this condition working propertly?

Comment: In user.service there's the following line `this.company = data.company;`. As for the if statement, no, that doesn't work. I've tried hard coding the values first to see if I could get it to work. I can't.

Answer (score 0):

I think correct way to go is to create rules in your firestore database, so that it is secure. I did mine using rules, check if the user owns the company, and grant the read access